# Is there a way to execute sql statement in sql server based on sql server version?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to create computed index on a table if sql server is 2008 or newer and a simple index if sql server is 2005 or older:

```
-- check for sql server version
if (select cast(left(cast(serverproperty('productversion') as varchar), 4) as decimal(5, 3))) >= 10 
        CREATE unique nonclustered index ix1_table
            ON table (column1, column2)
            WHERE column1 is not null and column2 is not null
        ELSE
            CREATE nonclustered index ix1_table
                ON table (column1, column2)
```

problem is that the whole statement is evaluated and on sql server 2005 this throws an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Is it possible to somehow create different index based on sql server version?

Thanks

Dragan